# Performance comparison of Nativescript vs Tabris.js

Tags: node.js, react-native, nativescript, tabris, tabris-js

Has anyone performed an analysis between NativeScript and Tabris.js to check which one performs better in Android and iOS? For example: in overall application responsiveness and any other metrics of system performance or benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have metrics, but from my experience TabrisJs is the fastest javascript framework currently, it is as fast as Flutter if not slightly faster.
NativeScript is slower than ReactNative which itself is not the top of speed.

Comment: Please past the link to studies or experements to buck up your clames

Comment: I don't remember the links, I had seen an article on Medium which made a comparison in terms of performance between React Native, and Flutter, with code on Github, Fractals, Mandlebrot ect...
Flutter was faster than React Native, I took the code that was used for the test for React Native and I adapted it for Tabris, the performance of Tabris was above that of Flutter.